# is there away to get image/video urls that already been uploaded to FirabseStorage in already old upload process without to upload again?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

For example i have the following steps

1- i uploaded video For Alex while he drawing
`FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('chatMedia/$randomId').putData(uint8List);`

2- later (after minutes or seconds or maybe days ) i want to upload the same Alex video that i already uploaded it in the past ..

is there away to get that `getDownloadURL()` without to upload it again ?

Comment: Does it work if you just call `getDownloadURL` again using the same ref path? Does it work if you save the URL you got the first time and reuse it?

Comment: '' Does it work if you just call getDownloadURL again using the same ref path? '' yes it is work but the problem that it has random Id , so the video came from user Gellery which has only path like /fo/fo/

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't use a random ID, then.  Or save the random ID so that you can find it again later using something else you do know.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @DougStevenson 

Comment: thanks doug , so i will accept this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you call `getDownloadURL` once after the upload completes, and save the result somewhere in a database record associated with the path of the uploaded image.  You can also call `getDownloadURL` as many times as you want to get a URL whenever it's needed.